# SharePoint 2016: Deploy Error - Unable to load one or more requested types.Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, farm-solution, visual-studio-2015

I have created basic `SharePoint 2016` Empty Project farm solution in which I have just created one custom list. When I am deploying the solution, got the error:

> Unable to load one or more requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Even in empty solution without any list, webpart or anything in the solution got the same error.
I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.

Comment: Which target frameworks are you using for? Please also check SharePoint dll references.

Comment: 4.5  All dll added to project.

Comment: Have you tried to clear my AppData/Local or to repair Visual studio setup from uninstall a program?

Comment: yes...... did it but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue with:

- Uninstall the Visual Studio 2015 Community.
- Cleared the `AppData/Local`.
- Install the Visual Studio 2015 Professional.
- Now able to deploy without any error.

Not sure that it was the issue of Community Edition or anything else but this resolved the issue.

Comment: I don't believe Community Edition supports SharePoint Server.  (I didn't think Pro did either as the SharePoint parts of MSDN are only in the Enterprise SKU)

Comment: which folder in "AppData/Local" ?

Answer (score 0):

Need to install SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components or SharePoint Server 2016 Client Components to solve this issue.