# establishing visual studio 2015 project connecting to SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, visual-studio

I'm new to SharePoint, but have knowledge in c# developing.
I have a SharePoint site that already has Lists in it.
I need to create a form (in visual studio environment) that could read and write data to and from these lists.

I've downloaded and installed Microsoft Office Developer Tools.

The Visual Studio and SharePoint are installed on the same server.

One of my major problems is that I can't even run an empty project without getting the debugging error-

> "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information."

I have changed all Copy Local to "True" - still doesn't help.

When I'll get through this error message I'll have to be able to read and write data from the lists that are already in the site.

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: we've had a similar case in another post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201510/sharepoint-2016-deploy-error-unable-to-load-one-or-more-requested-types-retri . Do you use Community Edition?