# SharePoint Solution Deployment Error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, solution-deployment, farm-solution, visual-studio-2015

Team,

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise (2015) Version-14.0.25420.1, Office Developer Tools latest preview is installed.

When I am trying to Build a SharePoint 2016 Empty Project, it Builds successfully.

But when trying to deploy, getting below error

> Error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I read this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201510/sharepoint-2016-deploy-error-unable-to-load-one-or-more-requested-types-retri/201895) that doesn't help me , due to the VS version.

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled this VS version and installed VS 2017 which resolved the issue.